# How to get the div class which contains another specific div class in Python with Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this kind of code:

```
<div class = first>
   <div class = second>
   <div class = fourth>
<div class = first>
   <div class = second>
   <div class = third> 
<div class = first>
   <div class = second>
   <div class = fourth>
```

The information in div third is different from div fourth, but I need the information in the div second which is in the same div first situated as div third is. So the div third I need just to identify the correct div second.

To be more precise: 
I need something that will do the following: If div.first contains div.third, then store the specific div.second (or the specific div first) of this element in a variable (to catch some text out of it).

I've tried it with find_all and parent or child operations, but I wasn't able to solve this.
Any help would be really appreciated.

**Update (example):**
An example with a flight search site:

```
<div class = booking class>
   <div class = price>
   <div class = non refundable>

<div class = booking class>
   <div class = price>
   <div class = refundable>

<div class = booking class>
   <div class = price>
   <div class = non refundable>
```

I need the content of the div class = price when div class = refundable.
Hope this makes it more clearly.

Comment: ...what? Could you give a less abstract example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume  when you say contains that you mean the *price div* is the parent of the refundable so look for the *refundable* divs and see if the parent is a div with the class name *price* you have what you need:

html = """

```
<div class ="booking class">
   <div class="price">
        <div class="refundable"></div>
   </div>

<div class = "booking class">
   <div class="price">
         <div class="non refundable"></div>
   </div>
</div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")


for div in soup.find_all( lambda tag: tag.name == "div" and tag.get('class') == ['refundable']):
    par = div.parent
     if par and par.name == "div" and par["class"] == ["price"]:
        print(par)
```

If they are siblings:

```
html = """
<div class ="booking class">
   <div class="price"> </div>
   <div class="refundable"></div>
 </div>

<div class ="booking class">
   <div class="price"> </div>
   <div class="non refundable"></div>
 </div>
 <div class ="booking class">
   <div class="price"> </div>
   <div class="non refundable"></div>
 </div>

"""
```

And the price always comes before use *find_previous_sibling*:

```
for div in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "div" and tag.get('class') == ['refundable']):
    sib = div.find_previous_sibling("div", "price")
    if sib:
       print(div.parent)
```

Or check behind and/or after:

```
for div in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "div" and tag.get('class') == ['refundable']):
    sib = div.find_previous_sibling("div", "price") or div.find_next_sibling("div", "price")
    if sib:
       print(div.parent)
```

If the div can be anywhere inside the parent:

```
for div in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "div" and tag.get('class') == ['refundable']):
    sib = div.parent.find("div", "price")
    if sib:
        print(div.parent)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Although the price div is a sibling (and not a parent) from the refundable div, I can work with it. As it filters out the parent of both siblings (price and refundable) I have both div classes in one filter and can use another for - loop to find what I need. Amazing! P.S. Do you know if it works with sibling too? Cause I tried par = div.sibling without success.

Comment: @Kimsbrand, I added  a few examples

Comment: Thank you so much!